# How to fix print output when integers are input

Tags: java, output, java.util.scanner

If I input '0', '1', '2', or '3' (in that specific order) the program's output is perfect. If I input the integers in a different order, the code does not work correctly. For example, if I select '2' first, my code expects me to input the integer a total of three times for it to give me the correct output. Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

I've tried using else-if statements and when I input anything other than '0', I need to input the integer a total of times equal to the index number. For example, if I input '2', I have to input it a total of three times to get my desired output.

```
System.out.println("Please input a number between zero to 3");

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                if (sc.nextInt() == 0) {
                    System.out.println("You have selected " + right);
                }
                if (sc.nextInt() == 1) {
                    System.out.println("You have selected " + left);
                }
                if (sc.nextInt() == 2) {
                    System.out.println("You have selected " + up);
                }
                if (sc.nextInt() == 3) {
                    System.out.println("You have selected " + down);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

My expected output should be:

> ```
> This program simulates the 4 arrows RIGHT, LEFT, UP, DOWN using the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3 respectively
> Please input a number between zero to 3
> 3
> You have selected DOWN
> 1
> You have selected LEFT
> 0
> You have selected RIGHT
> 2
> You have selected UP
>
> Process finished with exit code 0
> ```

---

This output happens when I put them in the correct order. If I start by inputting '1', this happens:

> ```
> This program simulates the 4 arrows RIGHT, LEFT, UP, DOWN using the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3 respectively
> Please input a number between zero to 3
> 1
> 1
> You have selected LEFT
> ```

Comment: You're calling `nextInt()` in every `if` statement. Think about what that does.

Comment: My understanding (which is limited), is that I'm calling nextInt() because I'm looking for a specific integer input from the scanner.

Comment: save the input to a variable: int direction = sc.nextInt(); and do the if checks on that variable.

Comment: `nextInt()` consumes the input that it returns. If you call it 4 times, it will expect 4 integers from stdin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your logic to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    System.out.println("Please input a number between zero to 3");
    // use input and don't advance the scanner every time
    int input = sc.nextInt();

    if (input == 0) {
        System.out.println("You have selected " + right);
    }
    if (input == 1) {
        System.out.println("You have selected " + left);
    }

    // so on and so forth

}
```

By using `sc.nextInt()` *four* times, you are looking for the next token of the input which isn't there. So fetch the input for *each* run of the for-loop and it will work as expected.

Comment: This seems to work, however, it does not let me input integers a total of 4 times. The code will 'break' and end after only one input.

Comment: It does. Also, that might have something to do with the `break` statement (depending on *what* input you are giving.)

Comment: I just realized that if I remove the 'break' statement, the code runs and terminates after 4 tries. Thank you for your assistance!!